# How to set up make to find the dependencies of autogenerated files that need to be compiled

Tags: c, makefile

I have a python script that needs to run before any other rule because it generates a few .c files that I want to compile.  But there lies the problems.

In my make file I have a rule to make the depends

```
SRC = autogenerated_file1.c autogenerated_file2.c

depend dep: .depend
include .depend
```

But the problem is the files dont exist when the make file is run to make the depends, I need the python script to run first, how would I set up a rule to run before the include of the depends.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I simplified my makefile and provided it here:

```
SUBDIRS = ../modules/mod1 \
          ../modules/mod2 \
          ../modules/mod3

CFLAGS=-g -Wall 
ARFLAGS=rs

CFLAGS:=$(CFLAGS) -I. 

APPLICATION_FILES = main.c autogen1.c autogen2.c

APPLICATION_OBJ=$(APPLICATION_FILES:.c=.o)

-include $(APPLICATION_FILES:.c=.d)

.PHONY: dummy
dummy:
    cd ../scripts && \
    python autgen_files.py

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

clean :
    rm -f *.o *.elf *.d
    -for d in $(SUBDIRS); do (cd $$d; $(MAKE) clean ); done

%.fin: dummy $(SUBDIRS) %.elf

$(SUBDIRS):
    $(MAKE) -C $@

%.d : %.c
    $(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) $*.c > $*.d

%.elf: $(APPLICATION_OBJ)
    $(CC) -Tapp.ld $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

The problem here is the autogen1.c and autogen2.c are not available at the start of make.  And if I do what I provided above I get caught it a loop of recursive make.

I should say the way I start the build is "make test.fin"

Answer (score 0):

If the python script generates the file `.depend` (that's my understanding but I'm not entirely sure), then add this rule:

```
.depend: script.py
      $<
```

This way make will know that `.depend` is also a target that needs to be made, and will run `script.py` if it's newer than `.depend` or if `.depend` does not exist. Tweak to taste.

Note that this might only work with GNU Make.

Comment: This doesnt work, I keep getting MAKE_RESTARTS and keeps calling python script code in a loop...

Comment: Works for me.  Are you absolutely sure your make is GNU Make?  does your script actually generate `.depend`?  Perhaps your script's date is in the future, so it's always newer than `.depend`?  That's all the ideas I have at this point...